# Orientation mode as landscape for only one screen - iPhone

Tags: ios, titanium, orientation, landscape, portrait

Im developing an application using Titanium which is compatible for iPhone. I'm navigating between 4 views.
1st View (Portrait) ---> 2nd View (Landscape) --> 3rd View (Portrait) ---> 4th View (Portrait)
SO I have 3 Portrait views in my application and I used *Tiapp.xml* and add

```
<orientations device="iphone">
     <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
</orientations>
```

For 2nd View I used following code ;

```
var winCheckInLogin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : "black",
    orientationModes : [Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT],
    navBarHidden : true, // Hides the native title bar
});

winCheckInLogin.addEventListener("open", function() {
    Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT;
});
```

But for the loading time 2nd View appear on Portrait mode after I rotate my device it keep it as Landscape. I need to load it as Landscape mode and lock that screen as it is.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: wt u want?? plz explain in sort

Comment: hi @iPatel : please look into this link . http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148143/orientation-mode-as-landscape-for-only-one-screen---iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gayan,
Using different orientation modes for a single app in iPhone is not recommended. Please read [**Orientation design principles**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Orientation)

> [Apple's Developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1) says: "People expect to use your
> app in different orientations, and it’s best when you can fulfill that
> expectation." In other words, don't look at handling orientation as a
> bother but an opportunity.
>
> Apple further recommends that when choosing to lock or support
> orientation, **you should consider following these principles:**
>
> On iPhone/iPod Touch – **Don't mix orientation of windows within a single app; so, either lock orientation for the whole app, or react to orientation changes.**
>
> On iPhone – don't support the portrait-upside-down orientation because that could leave the user with their phone upside-down when receiving a phone call.

However, if you want to use different orientations, just add the following to your tiApp.xml under `<orientations device="iphone">` tag

```
<orientations device="iphone">
     <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
     <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
</orientations>
```

This will do the trick for you!!

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-orientationModes

Answer (score 1):

In your tiapp.xml

```
<orientations device="iphone">
     <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
     <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
     <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
</orientations>
```

For all Windows (and not views), be sure to add the property of that window as:

```
orientationModes: [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT]
```

for Portrait-only Windows,

and for lanscape-only:

```
orientationModes: [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]
```

That should do the trick you're looking for.